# Can correlation analysis be applied on data of control vs treatment study?

Tags: correlation

This might be a weird question, but I have been asking myself the question for quite some days so I hope that someone can help me out: I have conducted an in vitro experiment where cells were treated with or without a compound. As a readout, I have received many data (inflammation; cell structure; etc.) and was now thinking whether it is possible to perform a correlation analysis on these readout data that I have obtained. There reason I would like to do this, is because it can give me a first (potential) indication of linked pathways when the compound is added to the cells.
So my question: is such a correlation analysis possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can correlate any continuous variables (and some that aren't) that are taken from the same cases.

But will this give you a "a first (potential) indication of linked pathways when the compound is added to the cells."   I don't see that this would be a good method. Your goal appears to be both causal (adding the compound does something) and temporal (it happens over time) and correlations are typically static and famously do not imply causation.

To formulate a linked pathway, I think you want to use substantive knowledge to formulate a hypothesis or research question and then figure out a way to test that hypothesis or answer that research question.  Once you do this, then people here may be able to help you figure those things out, but we'd likely need a lot more detail.

Also, while I am not a biologist at all, I'm wondering how cell structure could be continuous (I'm not saying it *can't*, it just strikes this layperson as something that is likely to be categorical).

EDIT One more thought: Correlation is only about the linear relationship. It doesn't detect change over time. E.g. if you look at weight of people before and after a diet/exercise regime, then, if everyone loses roughly the same amount, the correlation will be high.

Comment: Dear Peter, thank you very much for your clear reply. This is exactly what I was looking for! The idea was indeed to use information from this correlation as a starting point to initiate a new hypothesis that would be tested in a new experiment. I understand your point regarding data of cell structure likely being categorical; this involves gene expression data of genes related to the cytoskeleton. Therefore, I think the data are continuous. One final question: when you say 'that are taken from the same cases' in sentence 1, you mean only from the treatment or only from the control group?

Comment: I meant that, to run a correlation, the two sets of data have to match on something. E.g. if you wanted to correlate height and weight, the measures would have to be on the same people.

Comment: Good. If my answer meets your needs, could you accept it? Thanks